# What is the difference between struct node**hashTable and struct node*hashTable[MAXSIZE]?

Tags: c, syntax

I am having a bit of trouble understanding the difference between these two.. are both of these a pointer to a pointer?? and also, what are the appropriate cases in which each of them would be ideal to use??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct node *hash1[MAXSIZE];
struct node **hash2 = hash1;
```

The first creates an array of MAXSIZE elements, but each element is a pointer to a `struct node`.

The second creates a single variable, a pointer to a pointer, which is initialized with the address of the zeroth pointer in the `hash1`.

You might use the second notation in the parameter list of a function, or when you need a single reference to an entire hash table.  You use the first when you lay out memory, creating a hash table which can be modified later.

Answer (score 0):

The first is a pointer to pointer to `struct node`, the second is an array of `MAXSIZE` pointers to `struct node`.

Use the C operator precedence rules to untangle the types.